# Fill the region bounded by two path in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to fill the region (with gray!50) bounded by two path in TikZ? I have tried many solutions, but they all don't work.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.7]
\draw[semithick] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,2) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
\draw[name path=f, semithick] (1,1) circle (1);
\draw[name path=g, semithick] (0,0) arc (270:360:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Namely, I want something like this:
[image]

Comment: You should know to make your code compilable!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}% <- not needed for the below code
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.7]
\begin{scope}
 \clip  (1,1) circle [radius=1];
\fill[gray]  (0,0) arc[start angle=270,end angle=360,radius=2] |- cycle;
\end{scope}
\draw[semithick] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\draw[name path=f, semithick] (1,1) circle [radius=1];
\draw[name path=g, semithick] (0,0) arc[start angle=270,end angle=360,radius=2];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmh, just realize that the `\clip` strategy is the same as in hpekristiansen's answer. The only difference is that I fill first so that the line width stays intact.

Comment: Your method is better. I just did it quick without a `scope` to keep it simple.

Comment: I like `|- cycle` - I will have to keep that in mind.

Comment: @hpekristiansen One can also work with layers and so on. What is "better" depends on the context, which we do not know.

Answer (score 3):

`\clip` makes everything following only drawn inside the clip path.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\draw (0,0) arc (270:360:2);
\draw[clip] (1,1) circle (1);
\fill[gray!50] (0,0) arc (270:360:2) -- (2,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Filled moon shape]

Answer (score 3):

An other way to do it, without the clip command, is to fill the region first, then draw the lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.7]
\fill[gray!50] (1,1) circle (1);    % gray circle
\fill[white] (0,0) arc (270:360:2) -| cycle;    % white sector over
\draw[semithick] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,2) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
\draw[name path=f, semithick] (1,1) circle (1);
\draw[name path=g, semithick] (0,0) arc (270:360:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives the following

[image]